# What were the last words spoken in the movie Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi*, the latest movie (remastered, 2019), the last words spoken [would seem to be](https://www.scripts.com/script-pdf/1203) those between Han and Leia.  Han offers to part ways with Leia over her love for Luke; Leia confesses he is her brother.

But after this, during the extended scenes, the scene returns to Endor and celebration.  Chewbacca speaks to three different people/groups during the Endor scene.

Chewy's words are the last words of *Return of the Jedi*.  What does he say?

This is not trolling nor a facetious question.  Wookie is a translated language in canonical Star Wars, and the movie version has a definitive set of words said by characters.  The challenges that are faced by the community to determine a translation of Wookie does not make the question unanswerable.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted.  The answer is at-worst interesting, and at-best an Easter egg.

Comment: Because droid-speak and wookie are never shown directly translated in the movies, it’s asking a question that can’t be answered. It’s like asking what an ewok was saying

Comment: The actual last words in the (original) soundtrack are “Celebrate the fight!  Power!  Celebrate the love.  Celebrate the love.  Celebrate the love.  Celebrate the love!”

Comment: also depends on special editions or not. The last line in the 1983 script is Leia's. So it also depends on what you mean by 'spoken' (ie - heard by the audience or just seeing a character possibly saying something but not hearing it). In the Special Editions there are crowd noises from various planets so it's possible there is some human dialouge audible after Leia's line.

Answer (score 6):

### Theatrical Cut

In the original version of Return of the Jedi (and in [the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)), the last intelligible words in Basic were spoken by Leia.

> "It's not like that at all. He's my brother"

Even if we taken into account Chewie's conversations with Lando, this is still followed by various Ewoks chanting the 'yub nub song' which translates [thusly](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ewok_Celebration):

> Celebrate the light; (Freedom!)
> Celebrate the might; (Power!)
> Celebrate the fight; (Glory!)
> Celebrate the love x 4.

---

### Radio Dramatisation

The [Radio drama version of RotJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio_series)#Return_of_the_Jedi) ends differently, with all of the surviving main cast having a chat. Luke ends up with Threepio.

> **Threepio:** *Pardon me, Master Luke, may I ask why you are staring into the darkness? What are you looking at?*
>
> **Luke:** *Not "what;" "who." Three comrades-in-arms. Obi-Wan Kenobi, Master Yoda ... and Anakin Skywalker.*
>
> **Threepio:** *My photoreceptors must be malfunctioning, sir. I don't see anything.*
>
> **Luke:** *But they're here. And they'll never be far from us. Their fire is back in the universe. Let it burn high and bright, to be see
> by friend and foe. The Jedi have returned.*

---

### Official (canon) novelisation.

It might interest you to know that in the official [canon novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!), we get some (loose) translation for Chewie's conversation with Lando. He's asking about the Falcon and Lando is lying to him about it being in good shape.

> All the rebels give a cheer as Lando, Nien Nunb, and Wedge come running in. Han and Chewie rush over to embrace Lando…and ask about the Falcon.
>
> “Not a scratch,” lies Lando, with a big smile

---

### Bluray Special Edition.

Horrifyingly, in the final cut of the film there's one more piece of dialogue after Leia's conversation with Han. A gungan ([not Jar Jar](https://talklikejarjarday.com/blog/262-does-jar-jar-exclaim-wesa-free-at-the-end-of-return-of-the-jedi)) can be heard shouting "Wesa free!" in the background as the shot pans along the main boulevard in Thede on Naboo.